# Related entry's doesn't work

Tags: related-entries

I run expression engine 2.9.2 but if I want to use related_entry's it display the tag on my front-end, I don't now what is wrong I have selected another entry. It looks like it doesn't understand the tag {related_entries id="dashcam_relatie"} because it displays as text. Also can I find nothing on EE only the v3 solutions

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="dashcam" limit="1" disable="member_data" paginate="bottom" track_views="two"}

...

{related_entries id="dashcam_relatie"}
        {title}
{/related_entries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

display

{related_entries id="dashcam_relatie"} display title from the active entry {/related_entries}

Answer (score 2):

Relationships changed in expressionengine 2.6. It looks like your template code won't work in 2.9.2. See the v2 docs on relationships: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/relationships.html

For example if your relationship field is called "dashcam_relatie" you might have something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="dashcam"}

    {dashcam_relatie}
            {dashcam_relatie:title}
    {/dashcam_relatie}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```